# Cycle2 carousel click on thumbnail to show content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**http://jsfiddle.net/r29A9/4/**

The actual site: http://sebastiangraz.com/projects/kbt/

(click the next and prev divs below to see the functionality)

Hi all I have a slight problem. I am using Cycle2 to slide some content and currently it's working fine the way I want it (check fiddle above). But I also want to be able to click on each thumbnail (round cyan/blue circle) and go to that specific content, once clicked.

To clarify further: There are basically two slides (one text and one circular-thumbnails) that I'm controlling with the next and prev div. So when I click on the circular div I want the corresponding text to slide in.

I discovered this snipped below on this page: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/caro-pager.php which I want to sort of copy the functionality from. And I have tried to integrate it with my current setup but to no avail.

```
var slideshows = $('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-next cycle-prev', function(e, opts) {
// advance the other slideshow
slideshows.not(this).cycle('goto', opts.currSlide);
});

$('#cycle-2 .cycle-slide').click(function(){
var index = $('#cycle-2').data('cycle.API').getSlideIndex(this);
slideshows.cycle('goto', index);
});
```

Do you guys have any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "go to that specific content once clicked"? As you are already there on the slide.

Comment: There are basically two slides (one text and one circular-thumbnails) that I'm controlling with the next and prev div. So when I click on the circular div I want the corresponding text to slide in.

Comment: Why don't you use only one slider?

Comment: I can't to that because of the way content is structured in WP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please find below the fiddle i have created which solves your problem

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sb_satchitanand/r29A9/8/)

```
($("#carousel1 .readmore").length - 1)
```

Gives the count for number of slides your are using & I'm subtracting 1 from it since, the plugin adds one more section which is the current section displayed.

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle. unfortunately the next and prev buttons does not work

Comment: Also check out http://sebastiangraz.com/projects/kbt/ (a more clear example of what I want to do) right now I can only click one step ahead. I want to be able to click any thumbnail

Comment: @SebastianGraz ohhhh my mistake!! I forgot to update the slideshow variable name in the function. I have updated the fiddle please verify

Comment: We are very close to a solution here I think :) The only problem I have now that sometimes the thumbnail is unclickable when going back, sometimes Look at http://sebastiangraz.com/projects/kbt/

Comment: @SebastianGraz For previous links to work I have updated the fiddle accordingly. Please verify.

Comment: That works correctly! Do you think it's possible to code it in a way that when you click for instance: "Service5" (http://sebastiangraz.com/projects/kbt/) it doesn't scroll backward to reveal the content but actually scroll to the thumbnail I clicked on? Makes any sense? Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @SebastianGraz With the current set of [commands](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/#commands) given by the API, we are using "goto". I have studied the API code for said command and it decides the transition forward effect depending upon the "index" we provide in goto. If the "next index" < "current index" which happens from last to first slide as well as in general(ex: 4->3 slide) the transition "fwd" is false and it is expected & this is the same behavior/transition when you click "prev" link. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: I'm guessing there is no way to override that functionality?

Comment: I guess its not possible, but I'm not sure.